# Azure DevOps projects directly publish to google play console

Tags: flutter, deployment, azure-devops, publish, google-play-console

I have uploaded my flutter mobile application to Azure DevOps. Now I want to directly publish my application on google play console. Is there any way to do that kind of things using azure?

can I use pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure devops provide way to publish directly to playstore. Need to create piline ,build and deploy to playstore. 
Need playstore private key to deploy on playstore.

Comment: is there any reference document on how to do it? can you please provide any reference?

Answer (score 4):

For this issue , I think azure devops does not support publishing the project directly to the google play console.

Azure devops support [Google Play](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsclient.google-play) extension.This extension contains a set of deployment tasks which allow you to automate the release, promotion and rollout of app updates to the Google Play store from your CI environment.  In order to automate the release of app updates to the Google Play store, you need to have manually released at least one version through the Google Play Developer Console.

If you want to publish to google play console , you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/publishing/publishing-to-google-play/?tabs=windows).

Comment: Azure DevOps provide flutter extensions. I think can use those extensions.

Comment: Great! You can try them, if they are feasible, you can share this solution as an answer here.